# ¿Como ver un dataframe la información completa de un archivo con extensión nc?

Tags: python, netcdf4

Hola estoy tratando de visualizar los datos en un archivo con extensión nc en un Dataframe, pero mi pregunta es:
¿Como puedo ver toda la información del dataframe localizada en el archivo con extensión nc?

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset('Mi_archivo.nc')
df = ds.to_dataframe()

print(df)
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: El código para abrir nc es correcto pero supongo que el resultado de ese dataframe contiene varios índices y alguna pérdida de información ¿ no ?

Comment: quisiera ver toda la inforración toda la información completa no es posible en un dataframe?

Comment: Si lo que deseas es únicamente ver la información bastaría con df.head(), el método head recibe la cantidad de rows que deseas ver, puedes pasarle df.head(9) por ejempo para ver 9. ¿ es eso ?

Comment: o sea el codigo me imprime todo el dataframe, pero yo quisiera ver toda la información en forma de dataframe, sin perder información